# Laravel 5 file upload validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation, file-upload

I'm using laravel built in file upload to upload video to my website. I've already successfully uploaded the file, but when my friend try to upload the video he got an error "validation.uploaded" i don't know why this is happening and i've been trying to find the error but i can't find it. We both try it in firefox and chrome but only my friend who got it. Please help this is my code:

Save Video Function

```
protected function saveVideo(UploadedFile $video)
{
    $fileName = str_random(40);

    $fullFileName = $fileName.'.'.$video->guessClientExtension();

    $video->storeAs('videos', $fileName);

    return $fullFileName;
}
```

Save From Form

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //dd($request->all());
    $video = Video::findOrFail($id);
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|unique:lessons,title,'.$video->id,
        'lesson_lists' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required'
    ]);
    $data = $request->only('title', 'description','lesson_lists');
    $data['slug'] = str_slug($request->title);

    if($request->hasFile('image')){
        $data['image'] = $this->saveImage($request->file('image'));
        if($video->image !== '') $this->deletePhoto($video->image);
    }

    if($request->hasFile('video')){
        $data['video'] = $this->saveVideo($request->file('video'));
        if($video->video !== '') $this->deleteVideo($video->video);
    }

    //$data['lesson_id'] = implode($request->get('lesson_lists'));
    $video->update($data);
    Session::flash("flash_notification", [
        "level"=>"success",
        "message"=>"Berhasil menyimpan $video->title"
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('video.index');
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with the same file? Check the file size of his video and check what the servers max upload file size is (and check if you got a size limitation in your form, as well).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thank you, apparently it just server upload limit configuration. after change it, it work like a charm

Comment: That's usually the case... :)

Comment: that was not the case for me, what is the problem? any more solutions please?

Answer (score 8):

Actually if the size of file you try to download exceeds the "upload_max_filesize" the Laravel shows this validation error, so you must open the php.ini file and set the options like this:

post_max_size = 500M

upload_max_filesize = 500M

*Notice: if you use wamp or xamp don't forget to restart it otherwise rerun the command:*

php artisan serve

Answer (score 1):

Laravel responses **422 Unprocessable Entity** which response body contains `validation.uploaded` due to exceed upload size limitation. Try to set proper value for following possible parameters(e.g. 10M):

`/etc/php.ini` (PHP):

- upload_max_filesize 10M
- post_max_size 10M

`.htaccess` (Apache):

- php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
- php_value post_max_size 10M

Then restart Apache `sudo systemctl restart httpd.service` (Cent OS 7)